# Need to get the pdf from grid to diplay in panel using ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, extjs4

I am new to ExtJS. I need a code on ExtJS to print the pdf version from the grid. I tried all the possible ways in stack overflow. but i need is, when i click the button, the grid values shown as pdf in panel and able to print. like google map. I need without servlet code interaction

thanks in advance..

Comment: You cannot create pdf with javascript. You have to do that on the server

Comment: You could try something like https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF. But of course, being HTML5-reliant, cross-browser compatibility is going to be an issue. As Darin mentioned, the sure fire cure is to do the PDF generation server-side. If you aren't able to interact with the server, I think you'll find it incredibly difficult to accomplish what you're wanting. I am curious--why do you "need" this without server code interaction?

Comment: Although not precisely what was requested, there is an extjs grid to print plugin demo [here](http://loianegroner.com/extjs/examples/extjs4-ux-gridprinter/) code [here](https://github.com/loiane/extjs4-ux-gridprinter)

Comment: @weeksdev is it possible to chage the print orientation from potrait to landscape.

Comment: @DarinKolev is it possible to chage the print orientation from potrait to landscape.

Comment: @existdissolve is it possible to chage the print orientation from potrait to landscape? how?

Comment: Typically, you would do that through the print dialog.

Comment: @Suresh I agree with existdissolve, that's something that the end user would designate typically in the print dialog.

Comment: @DarinKolev Pls help me for the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087958/timefield-combobox-issue-in-grid-using-extjs4